# Extending bash completion for a command in rosbash (with catkin_add_env_hooks)

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I plan to extend bash completion features for a common ros command (roslaunch) that already has completion defined in rosbash.

My first approach was to modify rosbash, which is quite generic and load my completion from there using rospack.
Now, I found [this commit](https://github.com/ros/catkin/commit/7247e4ea033e450c53102258c0811bb62932f816) using catkin_add_env_hooks to load completion scripts, which seems way more elegant.

First I am assuming this should work in any environment independent if catkin is used, correct?

The problem is that I am adding completion features instead of providing new completion. What is the correct way to do this?

I need to override the rosbash version here. rosbash is from 15.rosbash.bash, so I named my file 20.xxx and this seems to work, although I can't find any guarantees, especially about rosbash staying at 15. Maybe in the longrun the completion should be fully moved out of rosbash anyways and stay in the package that is completed?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63228/extending-bash-completion-for-a-command-in-rosbash-(with-catkin_add_env_hooks)/) by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31395 on 2013-05-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, in the long run it would make sense that each package provides its own completion. There is no "guarantee" that the rosbash env hooks will start with 15 but I don't see any reason why they should change.

So you can either:

- create your own package which provides an env hook with a higher prefix than 15 or
- contribute to the existing rosbash completion and send a pull request to improve the current completion which would be available to all ros users.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-05-23**:
You have a pull request.